# PHPExcel tweaking a core file

Tags: php, codeigniter, composer-php, phpexcel

I am using `PHPExcel` in `Codeigniter` installed via `composer`. I have installed the `PHPExcel` to manipulate some `spreadsheetML` files. My problem is with the `spreadsheetML` files because they do not have a default style values. I did the following tweak to a core file and got my problem solved.

```
../vendor/phpoffice/phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel2003XML.php
```

I modified the `Excel2003XML.php` file lines `413-417`

```
if ($styleID == 'Default') {
        $this->styles['Default'] = array();
    } else {
        $this->styles[$styleID] = $this->styles['Default'];
}
```

to

```
$this->styles[$styleID] = (isset($this->styles['Default'])) ? $this->styles['Default'] : array();
```

This solved my problem. But when I update the composer, I lose the changes. Can anyone help me to make the changes by extending the core file. So that I won't lose the changes when I update the library.

Comment: I am not familiar with this but it may be possible to extend this class and be able to keep your changes, just not in the core files.

Comment: Well, there are so many files and I `require` the autoload file and create the library file. So I am not sure how to apply the tweaked file to be used in the library.

Comment: Yeah I was looking through the files, it's fairly extensive...

Comment: Yep, any suggestions?

Comment: Where is the `Excel2003XML.php` located? What directory path?

Comment: It's located in `../vendor/phpoffice/phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel2003XML.php`

Comment: How do you implement this? Like `$whatever = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2003XML();` Something like that?

Comment: No, I actually extends the `PHPExcel` class and use the static method to create a reader.  `$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);`

Comment: And what is: `$inputFileType` equal?

Comment: It's the `spreadsheetML file` (location)

Comment: After muddling through it, it appears to me (don't take my word for it) that the `createReader()` method appears to send back a class using `$instance = new $className();` so I think you may be able to use the `addSearchLocation()` to add a place to search for a class, so you could probably add your own extended class of `PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2003XML` and call it still using `PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader()`...maybe...I would have to test that since I haven't really looked through it extensively.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. I will look into the proposed method as well.

Comment: @Rasclatt - the addSearchLocation() was deliberately provided specifically to allow customised user Reader and Writer extension, though I'm not aware that any users have ever actually done so... but kudos for looking through the code and recognising this option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code has already been fixed in the latest `develop` branch and the `1.8` branch on github, so if you coud update your composer.json accordingly, it would pull down a version of PHPExcel that already had this change.

Comment: I tried both 1.8.0 & 1.8.1 both gives me the error. `Message:  Undefined index: Default


Filename: Reader/Excel2003XML.php


Line Number: 417`

Comment: This is what I have in my `composer.json` file `"phpoffice/phpexcel": "1.8.1"`

Comment: Solved. I changed require statement to this. ` "phpoffice/phpexcel": "dev-master#6f43f0429b67c772381e64409496a7d1c77d8b66"`

Comment: Note that I Will be doing a 1.8.2 tagged release over the Christmas/New Year period, so this change will then be implemented in a formal production release